# PowerShell Setting up a folder to open in

Tags: powershell

My teacher gave me this instruction : "To set-up the default folder for PowerShell to open in, right click the PowerShell icon in the tool tray and select Properties. In the Properties dialog box and in the Start in: text box enter the path to the new directory “C:\Users\Administrator\MyScripts”, then click OK."

However when I go into the properties tab I do not see what he is talking about :( .

This is what I see:
[image: screenshot]

How do I I Do what he wants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your teacher is asking you to change the properties of the *executable*. You are currently looking at the PowerShell *console* properties.

As you can partially see mine is located:

%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

[image]

Comment: In hindsight I should have just commented on your answer rather than write my own, but here's what I should have said :)
I think it's important to distinguish that what must be modified is the properties of the _shortcut file pointing to_ the executable, not the executable's properties themselves.
Also, the question is about the _startup folder_ (`Start in:`), not the executable's location.

Comment: @mklement0 I understand that and (at least this time) I was aware of what the question was asking for. I wanted to tell the op where to find the exe that he would be needing to access if he was to follow the instructions exactly. I cannot guarantee how his OS or setup would allow him to find where his was. I was leading the OP to what I think he needed. Your distinction is an important one

Answer (score 0):

By "tool tray" I assume your teacher meant the **Windows taskbar** and by "to set-up" I assume he/she meant "to set up"<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFqoc.png)</sup>:

If you:

- right-click the PowerShell icon in the taskbar, you get a shortcut menu,
- in which you can right-click the *first entry in the last section* to **edit the properties of the *shortcut file that started the application***:

[image]

The resulting dialog will show you the desired `Start in:` field, which determines that shortcut file's startup folder:

[image]

Enter the desired startup folder (`C:\Users\Administrator\MyScripts` in your case), and click `OK`.

To determine the shortcut file's own location, switch to the `General` tab of the dialog and inspect the `Location:` field.

If you haven't yet pinned PowerShell to your taskbar, the `Location:` field probably contains `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Windows PowerShell`.

The shortcut file's own name is `Windows PowerShell.lnk`, though the `.lnk` extension is typically hidden.

In other words: by default, the shortcut file's full path is `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Windows PowerShell\Windows PowerShell.lnk`.

In general, shortcut files (`*.lnk`) store properties such as executable location, startup folder, initial window state, and shortcut key.

---

**As for what you've tried:**

As [Matt states in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3829407/matt), you've invoked the `Properties` dialog for the *open PowerShell console window* via its *system menu* (windows menu), which allows you to persistently change *window* properties, but not the startup folder.

---

<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFqoc.png) "To set up" is a [phrasal verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb) - no punctuation needed, and not to be confused with the *noun* derived from it, "setup".</sup>